# How to test 0x swap api on testnet?

Tags: 0x

Hello I m making a swap dapp with the help of 0x api I want to test it if it's working properly or not is there anyway I can test it on test net?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, can use our Goerli or Mumbai deployments (API endpoints here: https://docs.0x.org/introduction/0x-cheat-sheet)
or you can fork mainnet.
Examples of both methods plus code samples are in the [Working in Testnet](https://docs.0x.org/limit-orders-advanced-traders/guides/working-in-the-testnet) guide.